# I am looking to extract a substring from a given set of string using REGEXP_SUBSTR

Tags: regex, oracle

This is the provided string

```
MB/123456789/Load ABC,801774/123456789
```

Here i am required to extract the string after comma and before the slash. i.e.*801774*

For now i have used this query.

```
select TRAN_PARTICULAR,regexp_substr(regexp_substr(TRAN_PARTICULAR,'[^,]+',1,2),'[^/]+') from VW_TRANSACTION_SEARCH
```

This is working fine yet is there any alternative for optimizing this query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
regexp_substr('MB/123456789/Load ABC,801774/123456789',',([^,/]+)/',1, 1, NULL,1)
```

See the [online Oracle demo](https://rextester.com/PGPC46717) and a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/u0ysDc/1).

Here, `,([^,/]+)/` matches `,`, then captures into Group 1 any one or more chars other than `,` and `/` and then matches `/`. The last `1` argument tells `REGEXP_SUBSTR` to return the value in Group 1.

If you are sure there are only digits there, use `',(\d+)/'` or `',([0-9]+)/'`.

Comment: yes, there will only be digits at that position. This is working perfect. Thanks!